# Styling my app with custom colors

Tags: android, android-actionbar, customization, android-holo-everywhere

I'm trying to apply some styles to my app. I've created a custom theme for the ActionBar using this [actionbarstylegenerator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/).

But I want to change also in my app, the stock blue Holo color, to a red one, at least on buttons.

So, I have the custom theme for the ActionBar (Compat), and for the other side, a custom theme to change the Holo color.

In my app, I have defined the custom theme for the Actionbar, and I want to set the custom Holo theme inside the Actionbar's theme, but I don't know how to call, or where can I find the item name's whose define the variable you want to modify.

This is, I need to set this:

```
<style name="ColorTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black">
    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBoxColorTheme</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonColorTheme</item>
    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButtonColorTheme</item>
</style>
```

Inside of this:

```
<style name="Theme.CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/ab_selectable_background</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Transparent</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_customactionbartheme</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_customactionbartheme</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode</item>        
</style>
```

Comment: You might be interisting by this website, its a generator of style 

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: That's the one I have used, but only modifies Actionbar's style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to do this?

```
<style name="ColorTheme" parent="Theme.CustomActionBarTheme">
<item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBoxColorTheme</item>
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonColorTheme</item>
<item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButtonColorTheme</item>
```